# Whether to use [array].filter or _.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, ecmascript-5

my project includes underscorejs as a dependency. Internally I need to do a lot of complex array operations which basically includes me mapping over or filtering or reducing an array. We have native map, filter, reduce methods on Array.prototype. But the same methods are also available in underscorejs.

Personally, it makes more sense for me to use the native methods as it feels more natural in place of a wrapped object like `_(array).filter(function(){})` or maybe `_.filter(array, function(){})`.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

This is really an opinion based question. Lodash will give you better browser support and possibly better performance, while the native functions might be arguably more clear on what they are doing. The native functions also handle some edge cases with sparse arrays and such, which may or may not be relevant to you.

Whatever floats your boat.

Personally I'd go for consistency. If you are already using underscore or lodash for their functions that aren't natively implemented (like `_.uniq` or `_.pick`) I'd just keep using `_.filter` and whatnot too.

Answer (score 2):

If you need quite some complex operation go for underscore with the `_.chain()`

So you can chain call like this :

```
 _.chain(array).filter(function(){}).pluck('name').unique();
```

This sample will extract all unique name of the matched data in the filter.

Unlike native function, this library has been developped to be more easy to use and provide a good performance without having any problems with browser compatibility.

Comment: How would this be different from say `_.unique(_.pluck(arr.filter(item => {//filter}), 'name'))`?

Comment: @Populus your example is imperative and has bad readability, while the example above uses chaining, so it's declarative (functional programming) and it's easy to read.